# Filter products by specs in Gatsby

Tags: gatsby

I have an ecommerce Gatsby site that dynamically creates the pages for the categories of products for the path: `/products/${node.category_id}`

Now when you reach that page, it displays that specific category's products. Also, the page component selects all the different tech specs specified in the product's object and populates the filter with them so you can narrow down the results.

[image: Filter_image]

When the user presses any radio button from that list, what happens next?

I can't redirect the user to this same page because it's already built upon the page's GraphQL query (the query that selects category specific products) and I can't change the query to filter by spec as well, nor can I interpolate the query (forbidden by graphql).
Also, I can't add this filter params into the path because it's already busy with `/products/${node.category_id}`

Should I make a new `createPages` function in `gatsby-node.js` that creates pages on the `/products/${node.category_id}?` and it's GraphQL query takes into account the options selected by the user, so the path becomes `/products/${node.category_id}?diameter=15,25&length=100,200` and the query resolves the category as well as the filter params?